# Как что-бы дискорд бот ставил реакции под сообщения конкретного пользователя?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Крч, мне в голову взбрело написать собственного бота в дискорд чтобы смешно и всё-такое. Но главная идея заклчсалась в том, что-бы ставить одну кастомную реакцию под сообщением конкретного пользователя (постоянно. не зависимо от содержания, времени и т.п.) Просмотрев тыщю гайдов и туторов выяснил что можно вычленить айди юзера через режим разработчика, и от этого плясать, но т.к. в питоне я как в орфографии поэтому требуется помощь. Вот как сделать чтобы бот понимал айди и ставил реакт вот это вопрос.
вот код:**

```
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Система успешно взломана АЗАЗАЗАЗАЗАЗА')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'бот помоги':
            await message.channel.send('нет')

        if message.content == 'пися':
            await message.channel.send('попа')

        if message.content == 'да':
            await message.channel.send('филипкиркоров')

        if message.content == 'бот прив':
            await message.channel.send('пцвпаол')

        if message.content ==  ('бум'):
            await message.channel.send('123')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == '123':
            emoji = ':1hihihiha:1037993089593262091'
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('токен')
```

Comment: За вас напишут только фрилансеры, за скромные 500р. Здесь готовы только помочь, с чем конкретно - напишите

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий Денис, наверное я не совсем корректно поставил вопрос. Имелось ввиду что мне надо узнать как сделать так, что-бы бот понимал кто пишет, и если это тот, кто нужен, то ставил реакцию, а не просить написать код за меня.

Comment: @Perda4ello Исправьте ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно двумя способами - через уник. id пользователя - `message.author.id` или же его имя - `message.author.name`

Далее фильтровать можно через бд или же простым if-ом

```
if message.author.id == '1234554321':
    ...
elif message.author.name == 'username':
    ...
```

Comment: спасибо большое всё заработало!

Comment: Если решил ваш вопрос - был бы признателен за принятие моего ответа за решение проблемы